# Get total size of all databases with DBATools

Tags: dbatools

Using DBATools, is there a recommended way to get the summed total size of all DBs for a given server?

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-DbaDatabase $Server | Measure-Object -Sum SizeMb
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use Get-DbaDatabase as expressed in another answer, but I like to use [Get-DbaDbSpace](https://docs.dbatools.io/Get-DbaDbSpace) to get details for the individual database files, including file size, free space, percent used etc.

Some examples of this function are detailed in [this article](https://dbatools.io/size/), but a basic example to get the total data and log file size for all databases on an instance would be:

```
Get-DbaDbSpace -SqlInstance $ServerInstance | Select-Object -Property Database, @{ Name = 'FileSizeMB'; Expression = {  $_.FileSize.Megabyte } | Measure-Object -Sum FileSizeMB
```

Or possibly simplified to just:

```
Get-DbaDbSpace -SqlInstance $ServerInstance | Measure-Object -Sum $_.FileSize.Megabyte
```

The nice thing about Get-DbaDbSize is the various size and space fields are actually objects with sizes expressed from bytes through to terabytes, so you can return the data easily in the representation that best suits your average DB size.